# Use sudo to change file in root directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script to configure `resolv.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` automatically. I'm running the commands as "sudo", but I'm getting "Permission denied" errors.

```
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install vsftpd
sudo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
sudo python setinterfaces.py
sudo chattr +i /etc/network/interfaces
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install lamp-server^
```

Lines 2 and 3 get permission denied errors, but lines 1 and 5 did run. `setinterfaces.py` is supposed to overwrite `/etc/network/interfaces'.`setinterfaces.py`works when pointed at the home folder but not the`interfaces` file.

Any idea? Do I have to be changing ownership? Ideally I'd like this to be a one command script, where I can just call it and it will run. I'm writing this script for people who are not experienced in *nix.

Comment: Line 3 was failing because before I debugged `setinterfaces.py`, `sudo chattr` had already been run.

Comment: That second line isn't very likely to work, unless you actually have a program called `/usr/bin/nameserver\ 8.8.8.8`...

Comment: Actually, I failed to notice that particular point was already addressed in the accepted answer (it's missing the presumed `echo`). Sorry for the extra noise...

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't think it's a duplicate at all. The answer there debugs that line, while the answer here explains why it is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sudo` command executes the command you give it under the `root` account. In its simplest form, the syntax is:

```
sudo command args...
```

For example:

```
sudo whoami
```

prints `root`.

If you type, as you did in your question:

```
sudo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

then it's not going to work; it will try to execute a command named `"nameserver 8.8.8.8"`, which doesn't exist.  The problem there is that you're missing the `echo` command.

This:

```
sudo "echo nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

still won't work because there's no command called `"echo nameserver 8.8.8.8"`. That entire string is passed to `sudo` as a single argument. It needs to see the command and each of its arguments as a separate argument.

So this:

```
sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

is getting closer -- but it still won't work. It executes the `echo` command as `root` -- but `echo` requires no special privileges, so there's no point in executing it as `root`.  The `>> /etc/resolv.conf` redirection is executed by your shell, which is running as you, not as `root`. Since you don't have permission to write to `/etc/resolv.conf`, the command fails. The `sudo` command never sees the redirection.

You need the redirection to be executed under the `root` account, which means that you need a shell process running as root. So the solution is:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf'
```

This launches a shell as a `root` process. That shell executes the command line `echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf`. Since you have a root shell executing both the `echo` and the output redirection, it should work.

(I suggest grabbing a copy of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file before doing this, just to make sure you can recover if you accidentally clobber it.)

Comment: Ok, thank you. So what if I ran the whole script as `sudo` instead of doing each and every line as `sudo`? Would that mitigate the redirect problem?

Comment: Ok thanks. I think that having `sudo` inside the script makes it less simpler to run, so I'll stick with it this way, but that's good to know next time I go to write a script like this. I played with both options and thought it wouldn't make a difference either way.

Answer (score 1):

Second line would be like this,

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.conf"
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why (the `>> /etc/resolve.conf` in the question is handled by the current shell, not by `sudo`).

Comment: @KeithThompson Yea, I've read something about sudo not applying to the right thing, but I don't really understand. And actually I don't understand why I'm running `sh -c` *inside* a shell script

Comment: `sudo echo .... >> /etc/resolv.conf` fails because it gives elevated permissions to the echo command (which doesn't need it), but not to the >> redirection (which does, since the destination file is owned by root). Wrapping the whole command sequence in sudo sh overcomes that

Comment: @JFA: See the answer I just posted.